# Is there any way to update the colorMapper values of a bokeh image?

Tags: python, bokeh, colormap

I wanted to do something like this:

```
imagen=p.image(image='img',x=0, y=0, dw=bines,dh=shots,palette='pal',source=source)
```

defining the source as:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(img=[],pal=[]))
```

and updating it when new data arrives to plot it with its own colormapper. Is it possible or should I manually scale the data keeping the palette? The code above won't accept the 'pal' value from the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the lower and upper limits of the `color_mapper` as follows:

```
imagen.glyph.color_mapper.high = vmax
imagen.glyph.color_mapper.low = vmin
```

where vmax and vmin are the upper and lower values of the color_mapper.